# Describing Distinct Equivalence Classes of a Relation

Tags: complex-numbers, relations, equivalence-relations

Suppose that $R$ is a relation on the set of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. The relation $R$ is defined as follows:

For any two complex numbers $w,z \in \mathbb{C}$, 
$$w R z \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{Re}(w)-\operatorname{Re}(z)=k, \quad \operatorname{Im}(w)-\operatorname{Im}(z) = l \sqrt{2}$$

for some integers $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Question: Describe the distinct equivalence classes of $R$.

How can I visualise the equivalence classes graphically?

Comment: Try re-writing as follows:
\begin{align*}
w R z & \iff \operatorname{Re}(w) - \operatorname{Re}(z) \in \mathbb{Z}, \operatorname{Im}(w) - \operatorname{Im}(z) \in \sqrt{2} \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}

Both of these should bear resemblance to an equivalence relation familiar from topology and/or abstract algebra.

Comment: Better expression:
$wRZ \iff w - z \in \mathbb{Z} + \sqrt{2} i \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @AJY Requesting you to consolidate and put it as a nice answer. There are many from the community who could benefit, and this question does not remain 'Unanswered' officially

Comment: ... or  a + bi R c + di  <=> a + bi = (a + k) + (b + root(2)l)i

Comment: I'm not sure what "visualize graphically" means exactly, but one can consider the distinct representative  numbers as all the numbers w where $0 \le Re(w) < 1$ and $0 \le Im(w) < \sqrt(2)$ and any other $a + bi R (a - \lfloor a \rfloor) + \sqrt 2 [\frac {b}{\sqrt 2} - \lfloor \frac {b}{\sqrt 2} \rfloor ]i$.  But I'm not sure that is what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we know that $$w R z \iff \operatorname{Re}(w)-\operatorname{Re}(z)=k, \quad \operatorname{Im}(w)-\operatorname{Im}(z) = l \sqrt{2}$$

for some integers $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$. This can be re-written as
$$w R z \iff \operatorname{Re}(w)-\operatorname{Re}(z) \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad \operatorname{Im}(w)-\operatorname{Im}(z) \in \sqrt{2} \mathbb{Z}$$

Consolidating these into one expression, we have that
\begin{align*}
w R z & \iff w - z \in \mathbb{Z} + \sqrt{2} i \mathbb{Z} \\
\Rightarrow w R z & \iff w \in \mathbb{Z} + \sqrt{2} i \mathbb{Z} + z \\
\Rightarrow [z] & = \mathbb{Z} + \sqrt{2} i \mathbb{Z} + z .
\end{align*}

Visually, this means that in the same way $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ makes a "grid" (more specifically a lattice, as you don't have the sides of the rectangle, only the vertices) of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, each of these equivalence classes makes a grid of the complex plane, where each equivalence class is a lattice that makes rectangles which are of length $1$ along the real axis, and length $\sqrt{2}$ along the imaginary axis. In other words, you can make the equivalence class $[z]$ by starting at $z$, gridding the plane with $1 \times \sqrt{2}$ rectangles (such that $z$ is a vertex of one of these rectangles), and then keeping only the vertices of the rectangles.

EDIT: In case you're unfamiliar, when given sets $A, B$, we define $A + B : = \{ a + b : a \in A, b \in B \}$. Similarly, we define $A + b : = \{ a + b : a \in A \}$.